# Twitter Oauth authentication error

Tags: r

I have written a code like this but am getting a check twitter oauth error in the last line

```
library("twitteR")
library("openssl")
library("httpuv")
library("twitteR")
library("tm")
library("stringr")
library("dplyr")

api_key <- " API_KEY"
api_secret <- "SECRET_KEY"
access_token <- "TOKEN"
access_secret <- "TOKEN_SECRET"

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_secret)
origop <- options("httr_oauth_cache")
options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE)
```

The error looks like this:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error
```

:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'

Can somebody help me?

Comment: 1. It's not a good idea to expose your keys to a public forum. You should now disable them and create new ones. 2. Library [`rtweet`](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet) is the successor to `twitteR`, so might be worth migrating to that.

Comment: My advice to everyone experiencing issues with `twitteR` is to ditch it for `rtweet`. Authentication is much easier in the latter package - http://rtweet.info/articles/auth.html.